# Get the path a propertie file in the maven resource directory src/main/resouces

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i want to read from my propertie file in the maven resource directory (src/main/resouces).
The path to the propertie file is called: `src/main/resouces/jsfatwork/messages`

The file is called test.properties.
I used JSF 2.2, Eclipse, Java Web Project
The webapp runs on a Tomcat 7

I write in the maven pom.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
     <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resouces/jsfatwork/messages</directory>
        <include>**/test.properties</include>
     </resource>
 </resources>
```

And write in my java file:
Properties prop= new Properties();

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
//load a properties file
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));         
       } catch(Exception e) {
            }
```

But it don't find the propertie file.
Can i read out the path how is find in the `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: what do you mean you don't find the property file?
Is it that it is not copied where you'd expect it, or that when you load it in java it's not found?

Comment: When i want to read the keys from the property file.

Comment: Watch out for the typo: "resouces". It should be "resources". Maven, by default, will copy files from `${basedir}/src/main/resources` into the generated Jar file. By fixing the typo, the entire `<resources>` block can be removed from the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try instead using

```
 properties.load(ThisClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/jsfatwork/messages/test.properties"));
```

Comment: Thank you. It work! Can you tell my why did this work?

Comment: I delete the write in the pom.xml and it still works.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Comment: Did you mean i need to specifying my resouce directory?

Comment: No, it is picked up automatically from src/main/resources per default.