# Write into a properties file from a maven project

Tags: java, mongodb, maven

I want to write to a properties file.
I also read from the properties file. Look here [Path for a properties file in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576146/get-the-path-a-propertie-file-in-the-maven-resource-directory-src-main-resouces)

```
public void setProperty(String coll, String bez) throws URISyntaxException {
    File file =null;
    Properties properties = getProperties();    
    URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/jsfatwork/messages/test.properties");
    URL url2 = PageServiceBean.class.getResource("/jsfatwork/messages/test.properties");                            
    try {      
        file = new File(url.toURI().getPath());             
        properties.setProperty(bez, coll);
        System.out.println("Ich habe einen Wert gesetzt"); 
        properties.store(new FileOutputStream(file), null);    
        System.out.println("Die Datei wurde gespeichert");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PageServiceBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);            
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
Ich habe einen Wert gesetzt
Die Datei wurde gespeichert
```

So I think it works, but after < 5 seconds I get an execption:

```
Warnung: Cannot serialize session attribute pageServiceBean for session 143CD5DE1C101E6A30515C585C32C02B
    java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1671)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1077)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:518)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5622)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3947)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
...
Schwerwiegend: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1671)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1077)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5622)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3947)
    ... 7 more
```

I use MongoDB as a database. But at this case I write to the properties file and not to the database. So I don't know why do I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer` Error.

And the properties in the files are not there, once I open the file after the exception.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.
I can't write in the propertie file in the class path, because in the classpath it is part of the war-file on the server. And after i write the data are not consistent any more. So you get the error.
The solution is to put the propertie file out of your classpath.
I used the `FileOutputStream` to write into my propertie File and use the eclipse `HOME PATH` as path.
is this a good solution or should i use a diffrent way to write in the propertie file?